# Coding a maths problem to find the difference between two numbers which could be negative

Tags: objective-c, math

I'm trying to write some c code (objective c) which will take a bank account balance and a desired balance from the user and produce a value which I can add or subtract from the current balance to achieve the desired balance.

I think I'm made things overcomplicated, heres what I have...

```
//get desired amount to variable dblDesiredBalance
//get balance from database to variable balFromDB

double addAmount = fabs(balFromDB) + fabs(dblDesiredBalance);
double minusAmount = fabs(dblDesiredBalance) - fabs(balFromDB);

// create amount to add to db
if (dblDesiredBalance < 0 ) {
    if (balFromDB < 0 ) {
        dblCommitToDB = balFromDB - minusAmount;
    } else {
        dblCommitToDB = balFromDB - addAmount;
    }
} else {
    if (balFromDB < 0 ) {
        dblCommitToDB = balFromDB + addAmount;
    } else {
        dblCommitToDB = balFromDB + minusAmount;
    }
}
// update db with dblCommitToDB
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirements. Why isn't this just `dblDesiredBalance - balFromDB` for the difference and `dblCommitToDB = dblDesiredBalance`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not start from simple algebra:

```
current_balance + delta = desired_balance
```

and then solve for delta:

```
delta = desired_balance - current_balance
```

This works independent of signs - you know algebraic rules and all.

Comment: Bah, my algebra and text problem understanding sucks sometimes. I'll just +1 your answer and delete my own. ;)

Comment: Sorry to sound thick, but whats delta ?

Comment: delta is a greek letter that is commonly used to represent a difference.  The difference between the current balance and the desired balance is the delta.